# Pandas - looping and writing to multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Right now, the loop in my code is overwriting the same row.
How do i go to a next row?

desired result: for each link the user input, the data will be written to a unique row

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd


def get_bullets(urls):
    urls = urls.split(",")
    for url in urls:
          page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
          soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
          sku = url.split('/')[5]
          content = soup.find('div', class_='js-productHighlights product-highlights c28 fs14 js-close')
          bullets = content.find_all('li', class_='top-section-list-item')        
          bullets_text = '\n'.join([ bullet.text for bullet in bullets ])

          temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[sku, bullets_text]], columns = ['sku','bullets'])
          temp_df.to_csv('book2.csv', index=False)

get_bullets(input('enter urls'))
```

user input is: `https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1473086-REG/canon_3453c001_eos_rebel_sl3_dslr.html,https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1346734-REG/canon_eos_6d_mark_ii.html`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over writing the data in the csv of each loop. Perhaps store the result from each loop in a list then concatenate the results before writing to disk?

```
def get_bullets(urls):
    urls = urls.split(",")
    dfs = []
    for url in urls:
        # do loop stuff
        temp_df = ...
        dfs.append(temp_df)
    df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv('book2.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: i'm having hard time concatenating the result, would you mind write more detailed answer - I'd really appreciated it

Comment: Not really much else to say. Concat works like this:
`dfA = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3]}); dfB = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4,5,6]}); dfs = [dfA, dfB]; df = pd.concat(dfs)`. Try that simple example

Comment: heres the pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html